# joining two related tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have an **Orders** table in mysql that contains Orders of some products.

I have a **Cart** table too that is related to **Orders** table with an **AuthID**

**Orders Table Structure :**

```
id    |    name    |    AuthID

1     |     Ali    |      10
2     |    Reza    |      11
```

**Cart Table Structure :**

```
id    |    productID    |    AuthID

1     |        P1       |      10
2     |        P2       |      10
3     |        P3       |      10
4     |        P2       |      11
```

I want to Join **Orders** With **Cart** and just return all rows in **Orders** Table that means the query must return 2 rows

in simple word the **Cart** table is Cart of a shopping and i only want to show the **Orders** + apply some filter on products inside **Cart**

```
SELECT *, orders.id AS id, orders.name AS name FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN cart ON orders.authID = cart.authID
WHERE orders.id != '0'
ORDER BY orders.id DESC
```

Comment: that returns 4 rows (all rows in Cart Table) instead of returning 2 rows

Comment: That does sound like an issue, perhaps the probem is in the join, can we see the query that caused that?

Comment: @Mohammad Masoudian remove `*,` and select your need  2 rows.

Comment: you can see the query in my question

Comment: But that will really return 4 rows doesn't it because you're using AuthID which will match 4 items in the Cart table.

Comment: @rccoros yes i know but i need a query that only returns all rows in orders table + also i need apply some filters in cart table and if there is some situation i will not show the same AuthID from Orders Table

Comment: Can you show us what is the content of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Following Query Worked For Me :

```
SELECT *, orders.id AS id, orders.name AS name FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN cart ON orders.authID = cart.authID
WHERE orders.id != '0'
GROUP BY orders.authID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"select * from Orders left join Cart on Orders.AuthID=Cart.AuthID"
```

then we get two rows
otherwise interchange the tables, then we get four rows, but orders table items repeated.
we can only connect these two table by AuthID

Comment: The first query still returns 4 rows for me.

Answer (score 1):

If authID is unique in the `orders` table (as shown in your example), and you want to return just rows from the `orders` table, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT o.id
     , o.name
     , o.authID 
  FROM orders o
  JOIN ( SELECT c.authID
           FROM cart c
          WHERE 1=1
          GROUP
             BY c.authID
       ) q
   ON q.authID = o.authID
 WHERE o.id != '0'
 ORDER
    BY o.id DESC
```

Note that the inline view aliased as q returns a unique list of authID, which we can join to the orders table. This approach avoids "duplicating" rows returned.

---

An equivalent result can also be obtained with a query using a correlated subquery in a EXISTS predicate, like this:

```
SELECT o.id
     , o.name
     , o.authID 
  FROM orders o
 WHERE o.id != '0'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM cart c
                 WHERE c.authID = o.authID
                   AND 1=1
              )
 ORDER BY o.id DESC
```

NOTE: The 1=1 predicate is a placeholder for whatever conditions you want to apply on the rows in the `cart` table... e.g. c.color='Blue' or whatever.

---

Someone will also note that adding an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause, or adding the `DISTINCT` keyword with a select list that only references columns in the `orders` table would also work. I think the two solutions I provided better illustrate why you are getting multiple rows, and some approaches we can use to avoid that.